# Newton fwaas devstack installation verification

Tags: openstack, firewall, devstack, openstack-neutron

I have installed newton fwaas devstack by referring the following link for local.conf https://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/ref/local_conf.html

I got an error during installation soon after "tempest installation" in the process and installation was stopped.

Then I have followed the following commands 
1) chown -R stack devstack 
2) chmod 770 devstack 
3) cd devstack 
4) ./clean.sh 
5) ./stack.sh

By executing above commands installation is completed and I have got ip for dashboard. But when I am trying to check firewall list, rules its giving authentication error. First I did " ./openrc admin admin " in terminal and then the link I have followed for firewall CLI command is below. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Neutron/FWaaS/HowToInstall

Kindly let me know that is their any command to check whether FWaaS plugin is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the exact version of `FWaaS` you want to install, there are currently two versions : `FWaaS V1, FWaaS V2`. In you local.conf, you need to enable your preferred version e.g. for `FWaaS V2`, use  "`enable_service q-fwaas-v2`".

Please refer to [this link](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/neutron-fwaas/devstack.html) for more details.